# disable opera's builtin bookmark spam "redir.opera.com/bookmarks/"

Tags: bookmarks, opera, spam-prevention

Just noticed that I have a lot "spam-like" bookmarks in my Opera, just like

`"16000 games"` or `"Best booking service"`

Most links are `redir.opera.com/bookmarks/*`

also there are some links with "partnerid"-like parameter (referral system) with link not via redir.opera e.g `"www.avg.com/ww-en/opera"`

I think that they are builtin into the opera.

How can I disable them and prevent opera from recreating them in case of update?

Comment: They even says nothing about spam bookmarks in EULA http://www.opera.com/eula/browser/

Comment: That's one of the ways Opera makes money. They are not "spam", but affiliate links that those companies paid Opera to add to fresh profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you delete them, they won't come back.

The only way they'll "return" is by starting Opera up with a new profile (e.g. after you've deleted/renamed your current profile, or when installing a beta version).

Comment: Can I disable creating such spam even in new profiles?